# Can we add custom values to a CakePHP Table Object?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a Cake Object when querying a table:

```
$invoices = TableRegistry::get('invoices')->find('all', ['conditions' => ['order_number =' => $orderNumber]]);
```

This works fine. I then want to add other array key/values to this Object, like this one:

```
$invoicesTmp = array();
$invoicesTmp['customer'] = "name of customer";
```

But `$invoicesTmp` is incompatible with $invoices. (one is an array, other is an CakePHP Object)

I have tried this:

```
compact($invoices, $invoicesTmp);
```

but that didn't worked.

Comment: Maybe this can help you; https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#before-marshal

Comment: does it have to remain an object? And where is the data of the name of the customer stored? can't you just contain that data? or add a virtual field to the Invoices with the name of the customer?

Comment: @AlexStallen I am trying to switch between two tables that have different column names, and then output the info into one view. The view expects only some column names.

Comment: @WillParky93 Thank you for the link, I think this is exactly what I need. I'll try it in my code.

Comment: @WillParky93 I found that beforeMarshal is used only when validating data, it doesn't apply in my case. But thank you anyway!

Comment: "I am trying to switch between two tables that have different column names, and then output the info into one view. The view expects only some column names." It seems to me that your initial question is about how to do what you think you need to do in order to solve a problem you're seeing. But from the problem as expressed in this comment, I think that the best solution might be very different from what you're trying to do. Perhaps give us more information about the base problem and we may be able to point you in a more "Cakey" direction.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Fair enough :) I've made a page (controller file + ctp file) that shows the values from one row from a table. Then a new table was introduced in my project that has different column names, and I want that ctp page to read that table as well. That's my 'problem'. I know when I'm accessing the second table, so my logic was to create an empty Cake Object, then append the values from the second table to it and send the object to the ctp file. My goal is to not create other files, only that controller file + ctp file that manages both tables.

Comment: So, this is not a containment situation (records from the first table are connected to records from the second table), but rather that the page has a list of things which can come from one of two tables? If that's the case, then to make the second record "look like" the first record, you might use [virtual properties](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-properties), or you might [use aliases in your select statement](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-data).

Comment: @GregSchmidt you should use virtual properties on an entity when alias fields need to be serialized with the entity. I've updated my answer with a different approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `find()` method of a Table object returns a `Cake\ORM\Query` object. This object is used to build SQL queries and to execute them. It has some features to define how the results from the query should be returned.

When CakePHP fetches results from the database the records are stored as an array, and CakePHP then converts them to `Entity` objects. A process called "hydration" of entities. If you disable hydration the records are returned as just an array.

```
$query = TableRegistry::get('invoices')
                 ->find()
                 ->where(['order_number'=>$orderNumber])
                 ->enableHydration(false);

foreach($query as $record) {
    pr($record);
}
```

The above creates a query object, and you can iterate over the query records because the object itself supports iteration.

The query object implements the `Cake\Collection\CollectionInterface` interface, which means we can perform a bunch of collection methods on it. The most common method is the `toArray()`.

```
$invoices = TableRegistry::get('invoices')
                 ->find()
                 ->where(['order_number'=>$orderNumber])
                 ->enableHydration(false)
                 ->toArray();
```

The `$invoices` variable is now a valid array object holding the all the records with each record as an array object.

You can now easily use `array_merge` to assign extra metadata to each record.

```
$invoices = array_map(function($invoice) {
     return array_merge(['customer'=>'name of customer'], $invoice);
}, $invoices);

$this-set(compact('invoices'));
```

**Updated:**

Based upon the comments it appears you wish to use *two* different tables with different column names, but those columns represent the same data.

### Field Aliases

You can rename fields in the SQL query to share a common alias.

```
  $table = TableRegistry::get($whichTable ? 'table_a' : 'table_b');
  $records = $table->find()
               ->select([
                   'id',
                   'invoice_id',
                   'name' => ? $whichTable ? 'customer_name' : 'invoice_name'
               ])->all();
```

The above selects a different column for `name` depending upon which table is being used. This allows you to always use `$record->name` in your view no matter which table.

I don't like this approach, because it makes the source code of the view file appear to reference a property of the entity that doesn't really exist. You might get confused when returning to the code later.

### Field Mapping

From a MVC perspective. Only the controller knows what a view needs. So it's easier if you *express* this knowledge as a mapping.

```
  $map = [
      'id'=>'id',
      'invoice_id'=>'invoice_id',
      'name' => ? $whichTable ? 'customer_name' : 'invoice_name'
  ];
      
  $table = TableRegistry::get($whichTable ? 'table_a' : 'table_b');
  $records = $table->find()
               ->select(array_values($map))
               ->all();
  $this->set(compact('records','map'));
```

Later in your view to output the columns you do it like this:

```
  foreach($records as $record) {
        echo $record->get($map['name']);
  }
```

It becomes *verbose* as to what is happening, and why. You can see in the view that the controller provided a mapping between something called `name` and the actual field. You also know that the `$map` variable was injected by the controller. You now know where to go to change it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer!